# is graphiQL supports spring security ? graphiQL UI is not working after adding spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, spring-security-oauth2, graphiql

[JS CSS files are not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV8nt.png)

I tried below code for allowing js and css file

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                               "/configuration/ui",
                               "/swagger-resources/**",
                               "/configuration/security",
                               "/swagger-ui.html",
                               "/webjars/**",
                               "/graphiql",
                               "/resources/**"
                                );
}



  /*@Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**"); // #3
  }*/

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/*.js").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/*.css").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/*.html").permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable();
  }
```

I feel there is problem with Graphiql UI ?
Can anyone please help ?

For reference GraphiQL UI for query
[GraphiQL UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luGW5.png)

Answer (score 2):

I used the next matchers to allow rendering graphiQl

```
.antMatchers("/graphiql", "/vendor/**").permitAll()
```

GraphiQL version is 5.0.2

Comment: in which method? on `web.ignoring()` or `http.authorizeRequests()`?

Comment: http.authorizeRequests()